# Error in anagram code: python

Tags: python

This function will search for anagrams in a list from a .txt file, I want to be able to check for anagrams and return all anagrams of the word that I input, and if it's not an anagram it will return the input, when I do it in the code below, it iterates through the for loop then ignores my first if statement and heads directly to my else statement. How can I fix this?

```
def find_in_dict():

input_word = input("Enter input string)")

sorted_word = ''.join(sorted(input_word.strip()))

a_word = ''.join((input_word.strip()))

word_file = open("filename", "r")

word_list = {}

for text in word_file:
    simple_text = ''.join(sorted(text.strip()))
    word_list.update({text.strip(): simple_text})
alist = []
for key, val in word_list.items():
    if val == sorted_word:
        alist.append(key)
        return alist
    else:
        return "No words can be formed from:" + a_word
```

Comment: Make the condition in the if statement evaluate to true - python is not just "skipping" code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are making a `return` statement in the if and else branch, that will break the for (because `return` invoked inside a function do exactly that, interrupt the execution and return the value) , so, don't do that, just ask if the word is equal, and in the end, check if there is none occurrences (empty list)

```
for text in word_file:
    simple_text = ''.join(sorted(text.strip()))
    word_list.update({text.strip(): simple_text})
alist = []
for key, val in word_list.items():
    if val == sorted_word:
        alist.append(key)

if alist == []: print("No words can be formed from: " + a_word)
```